# Weird enable pins 74LV138D

Tags: decoder

The [74LV138D](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74LV138.pdf) is a low-voltage 3 to 8 binary decoder.

It has 3 enable pins, one for each of the inputs.

However, two of them are active high, and one is active low... Why on earth would they not pick one or the other?

[image: Datasheet Excerpt]

Comment: look at Fig 3 on page 2 of the datasheet ... do you still have the same question after that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "It has 3 enable pins, one for each of the inputs".  The three enable inputs used together enable or disable the output - they are not related to the inputs.

Look at the Function Table (Table 3) to see how the Enable pins affect the output of the chip.

The combination of two active High and one active Low enable pins gives the user more options for enabling the outputs than all-High or all-Low would provide.

Comment: Ahh, that's where my misunderstanding arose, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It has three enable pins to do useful things with it, such as combining two of the chips to get a 4-to-16 decoder and still have a common active low enable if necessary.

As the chip basically has six inputs, it is very useful in address bus decoding.